# How convert string to image using base 64 with huge data not displayed image while decode?

Tags: ios, base64

This is the string data i received from webservice.

[/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAgAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAgGBgcGBQgHBwcJCQg...](http://www.heypasteit.com/clip/0SAF)

Give me some suggestion how to fix it?i'm new to ios

Thanks,

Iniyarajan

Comment: Wow - this C# guide might give you some clues:
http://www.dailycoding.com/Posts/convert_image_to_base64_string_and_base64_string_to_image.aspx

Comment: What in the world are you trying to do? I'd suggest a different web service. :)